# Replace ID from CakePHP URL

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

How can I replace the /posts/view/**id** with /posts/view/**code** ?

code is a field in the database that contains 10 random numbers generated using mt_rand() function.

In the PostsController I have this function for viewing posts:

```
public function view($id = null) {
    $this->Post->id = $id;
    $this->set('post', $this->Post->read());
}
```

Now I want to use **code** instead of **id**.

Thank you for your answers!

**UPDATE:::**

Someone from the CakePHP Q&A solved my problem.

I'll put the codes here so if someone needs the same solution, it can be found here.

**in your routes.php add this code:**

```
Router::connect('/posts/view/:code', array('controller' => 'news', 'action' => 'view'), array('pass' => array('code')));
```

**in your controller change the view method like this:**

```
public function view($code = null) {
   $this->set('post', $this->Post->findByCode($code));
}
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: Why would you need to touch the routing at all?  Either your question is worded very strangely, or using the routes is overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i used cakePHP

just few times, but i think you should see routing in cakePHP, you should change rewrite of url

Answer (score 0):

I think that would be a URL like /posts/view/id/code. Then using the ID, you grab the code from the database:

```
public function view($id = null, $code = null) {
   $this->Post->id = $id;
   //..DO CAKEPHP QUERY TO GET CODE USING ID HERE. ASSIGN TO $code.
   $this->Post->code = $code;
   $this->set('post', $this->Post->read());
}
```

Comment: no, from /posts/view/id to /posts/view/code . . replacing the id part of the url with code